# How can I create a cell array in matlab combining text and number matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix

The following line works

```
array ={'a','b'; 1,2};
```

but

```
num = [1,2];
array ={'a','b'; num};
```

doesn't.

I also tried

```
array ={'a','b'; mat2cell(num)};
```

and

```
array ={'a','b'; num2cell(num)};
```

but neither of them worked. How can I produce a 2x2 cell matrix containing a, b, 1 and 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use concatenation:

```
array = [{'a','b'}; num2cell(num)]
```

Or extend the cell array as follows:

```
array = {'a','b'};
array(end+1,:) = num2cell(num);
```